# Trouble left-aligning last column in table (array, rotating)

Tags: tables

I'll keep it brief. I have this table:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array,rotating}
\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\raggedright
\caption{This is my caption.}
\scalebox{.85}[.85]{ 
\begin{tabular}[width=\textwidth]{>{\raggedright}p{4cm}>{\raggedright}p{3cm}ccccc>{\centering}p{3cm}p{3cm}}
\hline
Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3 & Column 4 & Column 5 & Column 6 & Column 7 & Column 8 with long title & Column 9 \\
\hline
Lorem & ipsum & dolor & sit & amet, & consectetuer & adipiscing & elit & Duis tellus. Donec ante dolor, iaculis nec... \\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image: Table 1]

I want that last column to be left-aligned, but changing the `tabular` specification to `{>{\raggedright}p{4cm}>{\raggedright}p{3cm}ccccc>{\centering}p{3cm}>{\raggedright}p{3cm}}` results in a mess:

[image: Bad table!]

What the heck is going on and how can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `tabular` environment doesn't recognize/process an optional argument of the form `[width=\textwidth]`. The only optional arguments `tabular` recognizes are position specifiers such as `t` and `b` (for top and bottom alignment, respectively; the default is `c` (centering)). The option `[width=\textwidth]` is simply ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your definition of left aligned cells is wrong. Instead it try to define new column type as:

```
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}
```

and than instead `>{\raggedright}p{3cm}` use `P{3cm}`. As you can see, error is in missing `\arraybackslash`.

Fragment of essential part of your code:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{array,rotating}

\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\raggedright
\caption{This is my caption.}
\scalebox{.85}[.85]{
\begin{tabular}{P{4cm}P{3cm}ccccc>{\centering}p{3cm}P{3cm}}
...
```

***Addendum:***
From TeX FAQ: *The problem is that the command `\\` means different things in different circumstances: the `tabular` environment switches the meaning to a value for use in the table, and `\centering`, `\raggedright` and `\raggedleft` all change the meaning to something incompatible. Note that the problem only arises in the last cell of a row. ... The `\tabularnewline` and `\arraybackslash` commands are (somewhat) modern additions to LaTeX and the array package, respectively.*

So, the command `\arraybackslash`, which resets the definition of `\\` to `\tabularnewline`, is really needed only in the last column.  Consequently, the use `>{\centering}p{3cm}` in this case in the last but one column doesn't cause error, and use `P{...}` in the first two columns show, that its use in other columns doesn't harm.  Of course, for consistency in this case is better to write:

```
\begin{tabular}{P{4cm}P{3cm}cccP{3cm}P{3cm}}
```

Comment: You may want to mention more explicitly that `\arraybackslash` shows its most important (beneficial) effects if used on the final column of the `tabular` environment.

Comment: @Mico, done! See addendum in my answer.